# How the RISC-V processor detect modes when handling exceptions?

Tags: riscv

I've read riscv-privileged manual and known if an interrupt or exception happen, the current mode will be saved in xPP (x maybe M or S).

But I found it difficult to understand these xpp bits in `xstatus`. xPP records the previous mode, but where is the ***current*** mode stored?

Also, I think this manual is brief but lacking examples.. 
https://riscv.org/specifications/privileged-isa/

Is there a recommended extra manuals for learning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will depend on your specific risc-v implementation.
E.g. I'm working on [RI5CY](https://github.com/pulp-platform/riscv) and s you can see in riscv_defines.sv, current mode holder is defined as:

```
// Privileged mode
typedef enum logic[1:0] {
PRIV_LVL_M = 2'b11,
PRIV_LVL_H = 2'b10,
PRIV_LVL_S = 2'b01,
PRIV_LVL_U = 2'b00
} PrivLvl_t;
```

And instantiated in riscv_core.sv

```
PrivLvl_t    current_priv_lvl;
```

Unfortunately I'm not aware on further documentation from the foundation.
Hope this helps

Comment: Got it. So I guess this means software(like OS)programmers do not need to care it.

Comment: @moon548834 Yes this should be transparent to you if you work at OS level.